# Why am I getting this error about XML Declaration?

Tags: xml, google-chrome

`This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`

This is what Google Chrome is showing me when the XML data is this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <tbl Src="JD-API">
    <cols>
      <col ID="0"Nam="ID" Typ="3" Wid="50" />
      <col ID="1"Nam="Text" Typ="1" Wid="50" />
    </cols>
    <rows>
    </rows>
  </tbl>
```

Why is it telling me this and what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the leading whitespace before the `<?xml` declaration.

Comment: Yup this is the solution to the problem

Comment: Don't think there is white space (at least not in the actual data, above it's just indented too far) but I will double-check the server isn't sending white space here...

Comment: I just checked and sure enough my HTTP server was feeding every line with 2 more spaces than it should have. Thanks!